# Using a variable to define a path

Tags: bash, path, cygwin

```
#!/bin/bash
SOURCE="/C/MSDFFiles/IPFiles/Source"

WORKING="/C/MSDFiles/IPFiles/Working"

rm -rf ./Working/*

cp "$SOURCE/"* "$WORKING/" 2> /dev/null

echo "DONE"
```

I am trying to copy all the files from source to working but its not working, my out put is done but files are not getting transferred in to working folder

Comment: Hiding errors with `2> /dev/null` won't help you find why it doesn't works :) Try removing the `2> /dev/null`

Comment: it dint work even if i remove 2> /dev/null

Comment: @Aparna Do `$SOURCE` and `$WORKING` exist? Any reason why you use absolute **and** relative paths anyway?

Comment: if i remove the 2> /dev/null part of code i am getting cp: target `\r' is not a directory

Comment: @htor they exist, the working folder may change its location, that is why i want the paths to be declared as variable and later move them to properties files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the error message

> cp: target `\r' is not a directory

there seems to be a problem with the line breaks in your script (`\r` is `Carriage Return`). Did you edit the file on Windows?

You should be able to remove those characters with something like

```
recode ibmpc..latin1 script.sh
```

or

```
mv script.sh script.tmp
cat script.tmp | tr -d '\r' > script.sh
rm script.tmp
```

or

```
sed -i "s/\r//g" script.sh
```

Comment: yes if i add 2> /dev/null file seem to run fine but cp action is not working as expected

Comment: @Aparna See updated answer. I added some ways to remove the spurious characters. The command just **seems** to run fine with `2>/dev/null`, because the redirection is suppressing the error message. That doesn't suppress the actual error, though.

Comment: @Aparna I don't understand how your comment is related to the answer Ansgar gave you?

Comment: even if i fix that special charaecter's, file transfer did not worked

Comment: After you removed the CR characters you should be getting a different error if `cp` still fails.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth - Ansgar is asking we to remove the characters which i am already handling with 2> /dev/null

Comment: @Aparna No you are not and what you are saying does not even make sense. Just try any of the solutions you were given in this answer and you will get a different error message, if any at all.

Comment: @Aparna You're misunderstanding what `2>/dev/null` does. Again, that redirection is merely suppressing the error **message**. The error itself is still there.

Comment: no i could able to see the "DONE" which iam printing at the end of the script, No errors but files are not copied

Comment: To clarify, the problem is probably with *your* script file *itself*, it has nothing to with the `cp` command, hence, `2>/dev/null` by definition cannot fix anything there (it never can, but that is another story ...).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers -  iam very new to Bash Scripting this is my first script so i have no idea what 2>/dev/null  does, but when i run my scipt with that line in my script it din't throw me any error that is what i know.  More over i runing the script in CYGWIN in my windows M?C

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - You want me to add recode ibmpc..latin1 script.sh at the end of the scipt?

Comment: @Aparna No. You should run one of the commands I suggested on your script file. If your script is named `foobar.sh` then run the command `recode ibmpc..latin1 foobar.sh` in the Cygwin command prompt.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - if i run just that line iam geting below error-bash: recode: command not found

Comment: @Aparna Check if your Cygwin installation includes `tr` or `sed` (`which tr` or `which sed` should produce the path to the respective command if it's installed). If none of the suggested commands is available, you'll have to install one of them.

Comment: Then try the `sed` solution.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - i did run the line sed -i "s/\r//" filename.sh, then i run the actuall file still it says ./TestBashFile.sh: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./TestBashFile.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
./TestBashFile.sh: line 7: $'\r': command not found
./TestBashFile.sh: line 9: $'\r': command not found

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - i could able to rsolve the /r issue...Thank you a tone,

Comment: But it says  cannot stat `/C/MSDFFiles/IPFiles/Source/*': No such file or directory
Where i have a soure folder and i have files in it

Comment: @Aparna Could this be a typo in your script? For `WORKING` you specify a path "/C/MSDFiles/IPFiles/Source", but for `SOURCE` the path is "/C/MSD **F** Files/IPFiles/Source" (with an additional "F").

Comment: i did copied the path and pasted in the script, below are my actual paths                                          SOURCE="/D:/Ms/IP/Source"

WORKING="/D:/Ms/IP/Working"

Comment: @Aparna I have very little experience with Cygwin, but I think that your paths must be either `D:/Ms/IP/...` (without a leading `/`) or `/cygdrive/d/Ms/IP/...` (lowercase `d` without `:`).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Thank you so much for your quick responce, my script  is workiing as expected now, Thank you a tone:-)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is likely the result of [your script's line endings being currupted by Windows](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/cp-target-%5Cr-is-not-a-directory-urgent-thanks-803622/). Linux line-endings are always `\n` (one newline) but in Windows they are `\r\n` (a carriage return followed by a newline).

Here you likely have a carriage return character after the path declarations.
Remove the carriage return characters from your script and it should resolve the problem.

If you are using `vim` you can view all non-printable characters in your file with `:set list` command.

Comment: i dont thing it is the problem with the carriage problem, instead of variables if i directly given the folder name files are getting transferred with the same script

Comment: @Aparna You "think"? Have you actually checked?

Comment: i did checked it iseems to work fine with folder names instead the variable

Comment: Variables will have the `\r` from the line ending in their value; hard-coded strings in the middle of a line will not.